# Why Display.getInstance().getProperty("pushType", "-1") value is "3" instead of "1" or "2"?

Tags: codenameone

I have this code in the main class:

```
 /**
     * Invoked when the push notification occurs
     *
     * @param value the value of the push notification
     */
    @Override
    public void push(String value) {
        Log.p("Received push message: " + value, Log.INFO);
        Server.executePushCallbacks(new PushMessage(value, Integer.parseInt(Display.getInstance().getProperty("pushType", "-1"))));
    }
```

I have an issue with `Display.getInstance().getProperty("pushType", "-1")`.

When the Push type is "3", `push(String value)` is invoked two times: the first time `getProperty("pushType", "-1")` returns "1" (visibile message), the second time returns "2" (invisible message). That's correct and expected, but it happens so only on the Simulator.

On both Android and iOS, `getProperty("pushType", "-1")` returns "3" both times, instead of "1" firstly and then "2".

Am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. We need to decide on the right behavior and do that both for the simulator and the device. I think we'll probably go with the device behavior but I'll defer that to Steve